# Service for minotoring keep-alive signals sent by services

Tags: windows-services, monitoring

I have a Windows Service that I want to monitor. Let's say this service may suddenly lose it internet connection, without the host system knowing.

I need a reliable online monitoring service that allows me to send a "I'm still alive" signal to, having them send me a mail, if my service has not "reported in" within the last X minutes.

All services I can find are regular monitoring services that connects to my website/service to see if they're running. I'm looking for a provider that allows me to do the opposite.

This seems like an insanely simple service, and I cannot understand how I cannot find anything usable anywhere? :\

Answer (score 1):

you need [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/).

Either use the client, or build your own custom instrumentation. You can do probably anything you like.

Update :

Another option is [scoutapp](https://www.scoutapp.com/).
Probably same features but with plugins.

Fiveruns was another option but I guess the are not in business anymore.

I can understand these features sound too much for your simpler scenario, why not build something for your own? All you need is a service that accepts a post and send an email to you.

Comment: They seem to offer what I need, and I'll try them out. It does however seem like a bit much for what I really need though. But thanks, I'll check them out. More suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I could build something myself, but for something like this, I'd prefer using an external service that guarantees a certain uptime and reliability.